# WoW LUA: MSP, combining GTAL?

Tags: api, lua, world-of-warcraft

While I understand it's best to start from the basics, I like to dabble. This is killing me though. In WoW, I use ElvUI and MyRolePlay (MRP) and the result is an issue with the enhanced tooltip. I've done quite  a bit of editing to the code and the only thing left is trying to get this last line formatting properly - the entirety (3 variables) on one line. I don't understand what gtal is (or the "L"), but it seems to create a new line. Is there a way to combine the gtal lines, while retaining the RGB colors for both respectively? I've tried to stay within the code style (since I'm having trouble bringing in new code) but due to how the author calls for colors on the variables, I couldn't manage to get the final %s its own color value without making a brand new line.

```
local dC = GetQuestDifficultyColor(level);
local cC = RAID_CLASS_COLORS[ classunloc ];
```

Best I could come up with,

```
gtal( format( L["|r%s|cffffffff %s"], e, emptynil( mrp.DisplayTooltip.RA( f.RA ) ) or race, class), dC.r, dC.g, dC.b ) 
gtal( format( L["|r%s"], class), cC.r, cC.g, cC.b )
```

There's no information on gtal in the mod or anywhere else that I could find. I hear the author is impossible to approach. But I was hoping someone got the idea here.

[Result of the two gtal lines](http://cubeupload.com/im/Kiss209/textbump.png) Perfect, if only the last word was on the line above it!

If it helps, the block all this is in is

```
local dC = GetQuestDifficultyColor(level);
local cC = RAID_CLASS_COLORS[ classunloc ];
if level ~= nil and level < 0 then
    e = L["|cffffffff(Boss)"]
else 
    e = format( L["|r%d|cffffffff"], level )
end
if mspsupported then
    gtal( format( L["|r%s|cffffffff %s"], e, emptynil( mrp.DisplayTooltip.RA( f.RA ) ) or race, class), dC.r, dC.g, dC.b ) 
    gtal( format( L["|r%s"], class), cC.r, cC.g, cC.b ) 
    n = nil
    t = nil
    if f.FR and f.FR ~= "" and f.FR ~= "0" then
        n = mrp.DisplayTooltip.FR( f.FR ) .. "  "
    end
```

and finally, this is what the original gtal looked like

```
gtal( format( L["%s %s |r%s|cffffffff (Player)"], e, emptynil( mrp.DisplayTooltip.RA( f.RA ) ) or race, class), r, g, b )
r, g, b = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
```

Update - this is what works here, since if this were ever helpful to anyone else:

```
    local dC = GetQuestDifficultyColor(level);
    local cC = RAID_CLASS_COLORS[ classunloc ];
    if level ~= nil and level < 0 then
        e = L["|cffffffff(Boss)"]
    else 
        e = format( L["|r%d|cffffffff"], level )
    end
    if mspsupported then
        local classStr = format("|cff%02x%02x%02x%s|r", cC.r * 255, cC.g * 255, cC.b * 255, class)
        local str = format( L["|r%s |cffffffff%s|r %s"], e, emptynil( mrp.DisplayTooltip.RA( f.RA ) ) or race, classStr)
        gtal(str, dC.r, dC.g, dC.b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gtal` is defined in `UI_Tooltip.lua`:

```
--[[
  EPIC KLUDGE!
  Special local functions to overwrite and add the current tooltip.
]]
-- Single string
local function gtal( n, r, g, b )
  local l = GameTooltip.mrpLines + 1
  GameTooltip.mrpLines = l

  r, g, b = (r or 1.0), (g or 1.0), (b or 1.0)

  --if GameTooltip.mrpLines <= GameTooltip.orgLines then
    -- Replace original line with ours, or add a new one if not there
    if _G["GameTooltipTextLeft"..tostring(l)] then
      if _G["GameTooltipTextLeft"..tostring(l)]:IsVisible() then
        if _G["GameTooltipTextRight"..tostring(l)] then
          _G["GameTooltipTextRight"..tostring(l)]:Hide()
        end
        _G["GameTooltipTextLeft"..tostring(l)]:SetText( n )
        _G["GameTooltipTextLeft"..tostring(l)]:SetTextColor( r, g, b )
      else
        GameTooltip:AddLine( n, r, g, b )
      end
    else
      GameTooltip:AddLine( n, r, g, b )
    end
end
```

`L` is conventionally your localization table lookup, used here in case you want a different format string for a different language.

In this case, it looks like `gtal` always adds a line, so you need to do your work all in the same line. Fortunately, WoW gives you inline color overrides that you can use! See [UI Escape Sequences](http://www.wowwiki.com/UI_escape_sequences) - that's what's going on with `|cxxxxxxxx` and whatnot in the strings. You probably want something like:

```
-- Build a color-formatted class string
local classStr = format("|c%02x%02x%02x%s|r", cC.r, cC.g, cC.b, class)
-- Build your tooltip line, which consists of `$e $race $class`
local str = format( L["|r%s |cffffffff%s|r %s"], e, emptynil( mrp.DisplayTooltip.RA( f.RA ) ) or race, classStr)
-- Add the line to the tooltip
gtal(str, dC.r, dC.g, dC.b)
```

Comment: What an incredible response. Thank you for the patience and tremendous help - What you wound up doing is very similar to what I had seen others do, particularly the well-written ElvUI:

`GameTooltip:AddDoubleLine(format("%s:", TARGET), format("|cff%02x%02x%02x%s|r", targetColor.r * 255, targetColor.g * 255, targetColor.b * 255, UnitName(unitTarget))`


And so I was able to borrow their idea on top of the work you did:

[link](http://cubeupload.com/im/Kiss209/learning.png)

With this working, I'll take to the basics -

Thank you again for the response and comprehensive answer!